# How to choose any number of elements through user input in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have created this script which currently is taking a list of arguments from command line but what I want to do is let the user pass any numerical value which would then start executing the loop for number of the times the user has asked. The script is run in the following way for example **./testing.sh launch 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8**. How can I make a user pass a numerical value like **8** which would then loop over the IPs instead of doing **1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8**. Also is there a better way to deal with so many IPs that I have passed in the script like for example map them and read them from a file.

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/expect

ips=()
tarts=()

launch_tarts () {
    local tart=$1
    local ip=${ip[tart]}
    
    echo "    ----  Launching Tart $1  ----  "
        sshpass -p "tart123" ssh -Y -X -L 5900:$ip:5901 tarts@$ip <<EOF1
        export DISPLAY=:1
        gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"pwd; cd /home/tarts; pwd; ./launch_tarts.sh exec bash\""
        exit
EOF1
}
    
kill_tarts () {
    local tart=$1
        local ip=${ip[tart]}

    echo "    ----  Killing Tart $1  ----   "
    sshpass -p "tart123"  ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no tarts@$ip <<EOF1
        . ./tartsenvironfile.8.1.1.0
        nohup yes | kill_tarts mcgdrv &
        nohup yes | kill_tarts server &
        pkill -f traf
        pkill -f terminal-server
        exit
EOF1
}

tarts_setup () {
    local tart=$1
        local ip=${ip[tart]}

    echo "    ----  Setting-Up Tart $1  ----   "
        sshpass -p "root12"  ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$ip <<EOF1
        pwd
        nohup yes | /etc/rc.d/init.d/lifconfig 
        su tarts
        nohup yes | vncserver 
        sleep 10
        exit
    exit
EOF1
}

ip[1]=10.171.0.10
ip[2]=10.171.0.11
ip[3]=10.171.0.12
ip[4]=10.171.0.13
ip[5]=10.171.0.14
ip[6]=10.171.0.15
ip[7]=10.171.0.16
ip[8]=10.171.0.17
ip[9]=10.171.0.18
ip[10]=10.171.0.19
ip[11]=10.171.0.20
ip[12]=10.171.0.21
ip[13]=10.171.0.100
ip[14]=10.171.0.101
ip[15]=10.171.0.102
ip[16]=10.171.0.103
ip[17]=10.171.0.104
ip[18]=10.171.0.105
ip[19]=10.171.0.106
ip[20]=10.171.0.107

case $1 in
    kill) function=kill_tarts;;
    launch) function=launch_tarts;; 
    setup) function=tarts_setup;;
    *) exit 1;;
esac 

shift

for tart in "$@"; do
    ($function $tart) &
    ips+=(${ip[tart]})
#   echo $ips
    tarts+=(${tart[@]})
#   echo $tarts
done
wait
```

Can someone guide please?

Comment: Just an observation, but you could generate the array `ip` in a loop, or declare it using a compound assignment like this: `ip=('1.2.3.4' '1.2.3.5' '1.2.3.6')`

Comment: `count(){ limit=$1; for ((i=1;i<=limit;i++)); do echo "$i"; done ; }` now you can `count 8` No need to involve any external tool from the shell, even POSIX shell can do arithmetic/counting on it's own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Try changing the bottom loop to: `for ((tart=1; tart<=$2; tart++))`, then use like: `./testing.sh launch 8`.
- You you can put multiple variable declarations on one line, so you could split the ip list in to two or three columns.
- Or use mapfile: `mapfile -t ip < ip-list`. You will need to use `tart - 1` for the array index though, like `"${ip[tart-1]}"`, as the array will start at 0, not 1.

Comment: Thanks I have posted another question as I have been facing issue with accessing the array on the last part.

Comment: Hi Dan, can you elaborate a bit more on the last part? I have tried to loop over ips from a file which I am able to but I dont know how to access using index.

Comment: Basically, your tarts start at 1, but arrays are indexed from 0 by default. When you use mapfile, the first IP will be copied to `"${ip[0]}"`, the second to `"${ip[1]}"` and so on. So for example, for `./testing.sh launch 6` and `action=$1 tarts=$2`, running `for ((tart=1; tart<=tarts; tart++)); do echo "action: $action, tart: $tart, IP: ${ip[tart-1]}"; done` would print the first 6 tart numbers and their IPs. But you also need to change the functions to include `tart=$1; ip=${ips[tart-1]}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan, really appreciate your help. I have now moved all the IPs to a file and am able to loop over the IPs. It has made the code more readable and the script looks a lot better.

Answer (score 2):

You want the `seq` command:

```
for x in $(seq 5); do
  echo $x
done
```

this will produce the output

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Then just take the number of iterations you want as another parameter on the command line, and use that in place of the hard coded `5` in my example.

`seq` just generates a sequence of numbers. From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/seq):

> **SYNOPSIS**
> seq [-w] [-f format] [-s string] [-t string] [first [incr]] last
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
> The seq utility prints a sequence of numbers, one per line >(default), from first (default 1), to near last as possible, in >increments of incr (default 1).  When first is larger than last the >default incr
> is -1.